# Are the following structs the same type?

Tags: c++

I have a struct defined as the following:

```
typedef struct {
    string foo;
} A, B;
```

I also have a set of functions as follows:

```
void Init(A *p) {
    p->foo;
}
void Init(B *p) {
    p->foo;
}
```

The gcc complains that Init is being redefined. Can I simply delete the second Init function? Is A the same type as B?

Comment: A and B mean the same thing (are the same type). Like `char *a` and `char a[10]`

Comment: `char * a` and `char a[10]` are NOT the same thing!

Comment: Is this intended to be C++ code or C code?

Comment: This is legacy C++ code that was written a long time ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, A and B are <strike>essentially</strike> just different aliases to the same type.

I think the code would be more clear if you give a name to the struct itself, and define `Init` as a function taking a pointer to the struct:

```
struct MyStruct{
    string foo;
};
typedef MyStruct A, B;

void Init(MyStruct *p) {
    p->foo;
}
```

It's just personal preference however.

Comment: Why do you say "essentially"? In which non-essential way are they *not* aliases of the same type?

Comment: @KerrekSB: well, possibly my English is not good enough and I chose a term that can be misinterpreted. What I meant is that the essence, the meaning of this syntax is to provide alternative names to the same type. I did not mean that any different interpretation may exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. B is an alias of A as defined on the struct definition

Answer (score 1):

They're both the same.  In C, because they are structurally the same,
and in C++, because the `A` is treated as the name of the type for
linkage purposes; this is almost the same as if you'd written:

```
struct A { string foo; };
typedef A B;
```

Comment: @Brad Because the standard says that `A` is treated as the name of the type "for linkage purposes".  I'm not sure what the full impact of this restriction is, so I prefer to hedge my statement with the "almost", even if I'm not aware of any particular case where there is a difference.